# Counting lowercase with regex

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I am trying to count the number of lower case characters in a string using regex.  I think I am missing something blindingly obvious but can't figure out what!  It is for an old classic ASP page.

```
<%
Password="abcd123"
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "(.*[a-z].*)"
Response.Write myRegExp.Execute(Password).Count
%>
```

The script returns 1 rather than 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your capturing group is wrong, this is enough: `([a-z])`. Using the `.*` you capture all that is around your lowercase character.

Comment: Thank you I have removed the .* from the pattern

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't just use `[a-z]` instead, because when you use `(.*[a-z].*)`, it will match all your input like one piece and not character by character?

You can check the difference here:
[[a-z] regex](https://regex101.com/r/ULgidk/1)
[`(.*[a-z].*)` Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/NBjxph/1)

I also suggest reading:

- [The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is what you want to do.

```vb
Password="abcd123"
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True ' This is required to get all matches
myRegExp.Pattern = "[a-z]"
Response.Write myRegExp.Execute(Password).Count
```

But I have some suggestions for you.

- You can make your rule greedy with `+`. This will reduce the cycles.
- You need to set `.Global` to `True` to get all matches, not only the first one.
- With this approach you need to loop through the matches collection (returned from `myRegExp.Execute`) to find the right result.

```vb
Password="abcd123fooBar"
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "[a-z]+"
myRegExp.Global = True
count = 0
For Each match In myRegExp.Execute(Password)
    count = count + match.Length
Next
Response.Write count 'prints 9
```

---

And here's another way to the same.

This matches with all non-lowercase characters and removes them from the result string. You can then get the length by using `Len` function.

```vb
Password="abcd123fooBar"
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "[^a-z]+"
myRegExp.Global = True
count = Len(myRegExp.Replace(Password, ""))
Response.Write count 'prints 9
```

Comment: Thanks for this - setting Global to true was the last piece of the jigsaw.

Comment: In fact I did not need to loop through I was able to just use:

Comment: myRegExp.Execute(Password).Count